# show button on longpress the grid item in android gridview

Tags: android, gridview, hide

Here i have using following code. Now my grid showing the download button on long press.If i long press another item it shows the button.But the problem is that previous button is there.I want to hide the old .(Hide the old download button on new Long press on another grid item).

How can i do ? Please check it and give me a idea to implement this part ?

```
   bookGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {                  
            downloadImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download);       
            shareImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);     
            downloadImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
            shareImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);       

    }}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: when you are clicking on one button ..hide another one..right now you are showing both visible.

Comment: I think you have to redraw your adapter again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remember previous long-clicked item:

```
private View previousItem;

bookGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            final int position, long id) {                  
        if (previousItem != null) {
            downloadImg=(ImageView) previousItem.findViewById(R.id.download);       
            shareImg=(ImageView) previousItem.findViewById(R.id.share);     
            downloadImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
            shareImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);       
        }
        downloadImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download);
        shareImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);
        downloadImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shareImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        previousItem = view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help for same activity.

```
grid1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {                  
            downloadImg1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download1);       
            shareImg1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share1);     
            downloadImg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
            shareImg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            downloadImg2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download2);       
            shareImg2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share2);     
            downloadImg2.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
            shareImg2.setVisibility(View.GONE); 


    }}
grid2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {                  
                downloadImg1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download1);       
                shareImg1=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share1);     
                downloadImg1.setVisibility(View.GONE);        
                shareImg1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                downloadImg2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download2);       
                shareImg2=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share2);     
                downloadImg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
                shareImg2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using custom adapter. You can create in your CustomAdapter method setButtonVisible(int position). And in the getView check this setted position and show or hide Button in view. Your method onClick kwill be something like this:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    final int position, long id) {                  
    adapter.setButtonVisible(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. Make a field or final variable with last button. in onItemLongClick check if it's not null and then make it invisible. On the end of onItemLongClick fill in the field variable with current button. 
   In your case (with provided code I suggest that downloading and shareImg are final variables common for all views that could be clicked):

   bookGrid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
           final int position, long id) {                  
       if (downloading != null) {
           downloadImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }
       if (shareImg != null) {
           shareImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       }

       downloadImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download);       
       shareImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);     
       downloadImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
       shareImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   ```

   }}
2. Make a button disappear after some time. But in this case the variable should be the method scope. E.g. :

   ```
       final ImageView downloadImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.download);       
       shareImg=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.share);     
       downloadImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);        
       shareImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
       downloadImg.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
               downloadImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           }
      }, 1000);
   ```